# Regular Expression to only get a specific line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to only extract a specific line without any other characters after. For example:

```
permit ip any any
permit oped any any eq 10.52.5.15
permit top any any (sdfg)
permit sdo any host 10.51.86.17 eq sdg
```

I would like to match only the first line `permit ip any any` and not the others. A thing to take note is that the second word `ip` can be any word.

Meaning, I find only `permit (anyword) any any` and if there was a character after the second any, do not match.

I tried to do `\bpermit.\w+.(?:any.any).([$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-\w].+)`but that finds the other lines except the `permit ip any any`. I did attempt to do a reverse lookup, but to no success.

Comment: Assuming you are using PCRE, `^permit \w+ any any$`; if your regex dialect doesn't support `\w`, please [edit] your question to reveal which regex tool or language you are using (these details are really mandatory as per the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info))

Comment: Im using Javascript and testing on the website regexr.com

Comment: I am unable to use the ^ and $ as the program I am implementing this on does not support multilines

Comment: Then it's not javascript regex. These anchors are mandatory parts of the javascript spec.

Comment: The program I'm implementing on supports standard Java-based RegEx. Im using Cisco Prime Infrastructure 3.1 to implement the regex

Comment: Then it does support `$` and `^`, and you should use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$` end of line anchor after the final "any" and the `m` multiline regexp flag.

```
/^permit \w+ any any$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/FfOp5k/2

If you are using Java based regex, you can include the multiline flag in the expression. This syntax is not supported by JavaScript regex.

```
(?m)^permit \w+ any$
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am only testing the expression on this website. The actual program I'm using to implement the expression, does not support multiline

Comment: What program is that? We can't answer your question without knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to do `\bpermit.\w+.(?:any.any).([$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-\w].+)` but that finds the other lines except the permit ip any any. I did attempt to do a reverse lookup, but to no success.

Lets take apart your regex to see what your regex says:

```
\b            # starting on a word boundary (space to non space or reverse)
permit        # look for the literal characters "permit" in that order
.             # followed by any character
\w+           # followed by word characters (letters, numbers, underscores)
.             # followed by any character
(?:           # followed by a non-capturing group that contains
    any       # the literal characters 'any'
    .         # any character
    any       # the literal characters 'any'
)   
.             # followed by any character <-- ERROR HERE!
(             # followed by a capturing group
[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-\w] # any one of these many characters or word characters
.+            # then any one character one or more times
)
```

The behavior you describe...

> but that finds the other lines except the permit ip any any.

matches what you've specified. Specifically, the regex above *requires* that there be characters after the 'any any'.  Because `permit \w+ any any` does not have any characters after the `any any` part, the regex fails at the `<-- ERROR HERE!` mark in my breakdown above.

If that last part must be captured (using a capturing group) but it may not exist, you can make that entire last part optional using the `?` character.

This would look like:

```
permit \w+ any any(?: (.+))?
```

for a breakdown of:

```
permit    # the word permit
[ ]       # a literal space
\w+       # one or more word characters
[ ]       # a literal space
any       # the word any
[ ]       # another literal space
any       # another any; all of this is requred.
(?:       # a non-capturing group to start the "optional" part
    [ ]   # a literal space after the any
    (.+)  # everything else, including spaces, and capture it in a group
)?        # end non-capturing group, but make it optional
```